# Form elements and image not aligned properly

Tags: css

I have this **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5V22F/2/)**, where i tried to align image (90X90px), Label and a selectbox to be placed properly (in same line). Image is aligned top whereas label & selectbox aligned at the bottom.

So far i tried to place everything in inline-block; float.. etc. but everything fails. What i want is i want to place everything horizontally center and vertically middle with only divisions. Can any one suggest me how to do this?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="center">
    <div class="search-wrapper">
        <img src="images/obj.png" width="40" height="40" class="search_img_txt"/>
         <h2>Lorem ipsum</h2>

        <select>
            <option value="am">1</option>
            <option value="am">2</option>               
        </select>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add following css in your code

```
.search-wrapper img{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
```

Check the updated [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/amoljawale/5V22F/3/)

Comment: One more thing, you don't need <div class="clear"></div>, cause there are no floated elements.

Comment: ok previously i tried with floats for placing image in same line, so i used clear.. now i will remove clear..